# RMWC Select label issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm testing Select component (controlled scenario) and it doesnt looks good on rendering. What can be a reason? Why this label looks so owful

```
import { Select } from '@rmwc/select';
import React from 'react';
import { type ChangeEvent } from 'react';

import '@rmwc/select/styles';

export default function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('Cookies');
  return (
    <Select
      label="Controlled"
      onChange={(evt: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) =>
        setValue(evt.target.value)
      }
      options={['Cookies', 'Pizza', 'Icecream']}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

[image]

It should like this one , when I clicked this manually and selected one option.

[image]